# If $f(x)=\dfrac{ax-8}{x-2}$ be tangent to the straight line $y=x+2$ then what is $a$?

Tags: calculus

> If $f(x)=\dfrac{ax-8}{x-2}$ be tangent to the line $g(x)=x+2$ Then what is $a$ ?

---

My try :

$$A(x_0,y_0)$$
first :

$$f(x_0)=y_0 =\dfrac{ax_0-8}{x_0-2}$$

$$g(x_0)=y_0=x_0+2$$

$$\dfrac{ax_0-8}{x_0-2}=x_0+2 \\x_0^2-4=ax_0-8$$

And

$$f'(x_0)=g'(x_0)\\\dfrac{-2a+8}{(x_0-2)^2}=1\\x_0^2-4x_0=-2a+4$$

Now what ?

Comment: Now you have two equations and two unknowns :-) You should try to solve this system of equations.

Comment: Now what : *Solve these equations, and enjoy!*

Comment: @JaideepKhare. $$ x_0=\dfrac{2a-8}{4-a}$$

Now what is $a$?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The equations of the two curves can be written as $$y=\dfrac{ax-8}{x-2}$$

and $$y=x+2$$

Equate the values of $y$ to form a quadratic equation in $x$ each of of the two roots represents the abscissa of the intersection.

For tangency, the two must be same.

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\dfrac{ax-8}{x-2}$ is tangent to $g(x)=x+2$

if the intersections of the line with the graph of the function are double. In other word if are coincident the solution of the equation

$\dfrac{ax-8}{x-2}=x+2$

$ax-8=x^2-4\to x^2-ax+4=0$

Solutions are coincident if the discriminant is zero

$a^2-16=0\to a=\pm 4$

Hope this helps

Comment: @Did and why did you downvote this? What is wrong here?

Comment: I didn't downvote, and I'm not the one you're talking to, but I would say this answer could be seen as weak for one of two (contradictory) reasons: The first is that others might have thought that hints would be better answers than full solutions for this question, and the second is that this answer isn't actually a full solution as it contains a spurious solution.

Comment: @Turambar I find my answers downvoted with any comment, and other "big" of the community getting $12$ upvotes for *trivial* observations which are not even answers... The one I was talking to is one of the "big" who is stalking me since a while with no reason.